How to send custom goal to Nav2?
I want to create a custom behavior tree with some additional functionality apart from navigation. I want to add functionality to automatically dock to a charging station when a command is received. From my understanding so far, the bt_navigator ticks the BT once a goal is received. I want to format the request to include some additional information to perform the docking action.
Can I send a custom goal to bt_navigator or does it require a goal on NavigateToPose action? Or is it possible to change the functionality of NavigateToPose?
PS. Another approach I had in mind was to run a separate BT which would publish the request to the nav BT whenever needed (will this work? and is it optimal?)
